# Softening the color of the line gradually

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I want to make grid line like this.

[image]

And, I made this one with wireframe.

[image]

But, I don't know how to softening the color of line gradually.

The color of the line is thinner toward the back.

What should I do?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Explore Depth of Field for you camera.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are 3 ways to do it in Cycles Render:

- With Mist: First go to your Render Layers menu > Passes > enable Mist. Now select your camera, go to the Object data menu > Display > enable Mist. Go to World menu > Mist Pass, and play with the length of the mist. Go to the Compositing, plug the Render Layer Mist output into the Factor of a Mix shader, and the Image into the top Image input of this Mix shader, then plug the output of the Mix Shader both in the input of the Viewer and the Compositer nodes. You can change the color of the mist with the bottom Image square of the Mix shader. You can add a Math node between the Render Layer and the Factor to change the mist intensity.
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxNeMMZs_sM
- With Volume Scatter: Create a box and increase its size until it contains your scene. Now in the Object menu > Display, choose Maximum Draw > Wire. Give it the following material: a simple Shader > Volume Scatter node plugged into the Volume of the Ouput. Lower down the node Density to something like 0.0X or 0.X. You can also add a Volume Absorption shader and mix it with the Volume Scatter in an Add Shader, so that the light is also absorbed.
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXjE-t6dFZ8
- With a Gradient Texture: Create a plane, assign it a material. Mix a Emission (white) and a Transparent in a Mix shader. In the Factor of this Mix shader, plug this node chain: Texture Coordinate that has its Object output plugged into a Mapping shader that has its Z Rotation 90°, that is plugged in a Gradient Texture node, that has its Color output plugged into a ColorRamp shader, that is plugged into the Mix Shader. Put this plane in front of your camera, behind your character, and play with the ColorRamp so that it fades your ground.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on these techniques. As it stands this is basically a link only answer

Comment: ok, it's done, I'll try to improve it later

Comment: >moonboots
Thank you very much for teach!!!
I succeed make softening the color of the line!!!
I used "With Mist". It's very good method. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 4):

In an NPR context like this one, this can be done with [Freestyle](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/index.html).

- Mark the lines of the grid (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Edge Data > Mark Freestyle)
- In Properties > Render tab, enable Freestyle
- In Properties > Render Layers tab > Freestyle Line Set, create a Line Set which includes 'Edge Mark' only
- With the Line Set selected in its list view, in Properties > Render Layers tab > Freestyle Line Style, select one or more of Color,  Alpha, and Thickness, and, in each, add a 'Distance from Camera' modifier to vary the style of the line by its distance from the camera, as you wish.

[image]

Comment: >Robin Betts
Thank you very much for teach!! I appreciate for you.