# Is it possible to make a transparent sequence with only mist?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

Is there a way to make an alpha layer containing mist, that could be animated, so I can overlay it onto another shot? Perhaps using a noise texture, and key-framing it? I'm not sure exactly if something like mist-pass would work, I haven't used it before.

Comment: yes why not? Here I gave the method for mist: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114207/softening-the-color-of-the-line-gradually

Comment: Based on the description below, won't the mist go away within the world settings once I select film>transparent within render properties?                                                                                           With Mist: First go to your Render Layers menu > Passes > enable Mist. Now select your camera, go to the Object data menu > Display > enable Mist. Go to World menu > Mist Pass, and play with the length of the mist. Go to the Compositing, plug the Render Layer Mist output into the Factor of a Mix shader, and the Image into the top Image input of this Mix shader (cont.)

Comment: I guess you can keep alpha transparency, but I can't be completely positive, you need to test