# How to make distance fog

Tags: rendering

I've been trying to use volume scattering to get this effect though it doesn't look as nice as this one does, with the blue-ish shade.
I was wondering what the trick is. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: the easiest and lightest way is to create a plane and give it a gradient (or image texture) that acts like a mask between a diffuse (or emission) blue and transparency, I gave a similar answer here (third point), tell me if it answers:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114207/softening-the-color-of-the-line-gradually

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to use this technique.

Comment: Read: [Low lying fog](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43600/low-lying-fog-bounding-object-rendering-as-solid)

Answer (score 5):

Use the mist pass. You can enable it by going to the Layer Properties and under "Passes", enable "Mist". Then, in the camera settings, under "Viewport Display", enable "Mist" so you can see where the mist begins and where it ends (the location where an object will be completely invisible, shrouded by mist). This can be adjusted in the World settings.

Now head to the compositor workspace and you will see a "Mist" output. Plug that into a coloramp. There you can adjust values, and clamp the pass as you want. It will make sense once you mix it with the output using a MixRGB set to "Add".

Here is a very quick youtube video I found detailing the parts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXXYUv-793c

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the mist pass and compositing you can create a cube the size of your scene and connect a principled volume shader to the volume socket of the material output. You can add noises and animate it, render times will be significant though. Hope that helps.

[image: Simple fog setup]