# How does mist pass work in Eevee?

Tags: world

I see tutorials for more advanced stuff and cycles, but how do you do a basic mist pass in Eevee? (The sort that would be in old games to hide draw distance)

I know it probably has something to do with the world node, but adding a volume scatter has weird colors, so I don't know what I'm supposed to do with it. It should also not effect any skybox etc, and I don't know how that would be done either.

Comment: I gave an answer here, tell me if it helps, and if not, what are you looking for different: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114207/softening-the-color-of-the-line-gradually