# Fog without volumetrics or emission

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes, volumetrics, emission

i´m currently working on a movie and need dark fog in my scene. It has to look more smoky, so it can't be as bright. With Volumetrics, the image is unfortunately still too noisy, even at high sample rates. Using Mist Pass in Blender or an Emission in general doesn't work because it brightens the room. Isn't there some other way to create fog that works in Cycles? Light does not have to be influenced by it. I can make Light Rays from different. I would be really grateful for any help!

Comment: you could use the third solution I give here, it's a kind of trick, but it's only for backgrounds, for 3D fog you need to use volumetrics: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114207/softening-the-color-of-the-line-gradually

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes the problem is, that i would need 3d fog for the animation 